# How to prove that primes congruent to $\pm1$ mod $5$ are of the form $5 a^2 - b^2$

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, quadratic-residues

I'm working through Reid's *Undergraduate Commutative Algebra* to prepare myself for Algebraic Geometry next semester, and one of the exercises (0.19) walks you through studying the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt5]$. Part of this analysis includes showing that if $5$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ (i.e., by quadratic reciprocity, $p \equiv \pm1 \pmod 5$), then $p$ is reducible. Reid says this can be shown using a modification of the argument that any prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ is of the form $3 a^2 + b^2$ outlined in exercise 0.14:

> pick any $a \in \mathbb Z$ with $a^2 \equiv -3 \mod p$ (this is possible by Ex. 0.13). Consider $x - a y$ as $(x, y)$ run independently through the integers in $[0, \sqrt p]$; there are > $p$ pairs $(x, y)$, hence they are not all distinct mod $p$. If $x_1 - a y_1 \equiv x_2 - a y_2$ then
> $$(x_1 - x_2)^2 + 3 (y_1 - y_2)^2 = N p \quad \text{with  $N = 1, 2$ or $3$.}$$
> Now $N = 2$ is impossible, and if $N = 3$ you can divide through.

Doing this, I was able to show that there are distinct pairs $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ such that $5(y_1 - y_2)^2 - (x_1 - x_2)^2 = N p$ with $N = 1$ or $N = 4$, but I've only been able to show you can divide through when $N = 4$ in the case both $x_1 - x_2, y_1 - y_2$ are even. Is there a way to complete this proof? Is there a better proof?

Comment: Do you know about binary quadratic forms? This has what you need: http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Cox-Primes_of_the_form_x2+ny2.pdf

Comment: Not really. Glancing through that book, it looks like it only addresses positive $n$; how applicable is what it says to negative $n$?

Comment: this is a good point yes. the theory is a bit different when $b^2 - 4ac = 0^2 - 4 \times 5 \times -1 = 20 > 0$.

Comment: On another note: it seems that you only need there to exist $x_i, y_i$ ($i \in \{1, 2\}$) with $5(y_1 - y_2)^2 - (x_1 - x_2)^2 = p$. Then you only need $x_1 - x_2$ and $y_1 - y_2$ even for some choice of the $x_i, y_i$? Perhaps I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, I want that there are $x_i, y_i$ with $5 (y_1 - y_2)^2 - (x_1 - x_2)^2 = p$. However, I've only been able to show that there are $x_i, y_i$ such that *either* that is true, or $5 (y_1 - y_2)^2 - (x_1 - x_2)^2 = 4 p$.

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor I'm guessing the facts that $5(1)^2 - 1^2 = 4$ and $5(1)^2 - 3^2 = -4$ should help with dividing by $4$.  Presumably one of these can be composed to multiply by $4$, with the extra minus sign probably being needed since it's $5a^2-b^2$ instead of $b^2 - 5a^2$.

Comment: @ErickWong would you mind spelling that out a bit? I know that if $5 c^2 + d^2$ is *prime* and divides $5 a^2 - b^2$, then the quotient is of the form $m^2 - 5 n^2$ (which also works, since we just need to be able to factor in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt5]$) but $\pm4$ aren't prime.

Comment: You have it backwards; the first paragraph says "if $5$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$".

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor Answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding and simplifying my previous comment:

Using a variant of the [Brahmagupta identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity), we have

$$-4(5a^2 - b^2) = (1^2 - 5\cdot 1^2)(5a^2 - b^2) = 5(a+b)^2 - (b+5a)^2.$$

This gives you a new mechanism with which you can divide by $-4$: if $4p = 5x^2 - y^2$, then $-p = 5[(y-x)/4]^2 - [(5x-y)/4]^2$.

Now, it may be that $y-x$ is not divisible by $4$, but in the case that $x$ and $y$ are both odd, then you can just replace $x \mapsto -x$ to fix that.  And you already know how to handle the case where $x$ and $y$ are both even.  (We leave it to the reader to explain why we don't consider the case where exactly one of $x,y$ is odd.)

Once you have $-p$ represented by some $5r^2 - s^2$, it's easy to flip the sign using Brahmagupta again with $2^2 - 5\cdot 1^2 = -1$.